# {} + "" vs "" + {} - Consistency in Addition

Tags: javascript

I stumbled across this the other day on reddit. The poster noted that

```
{} + ""
```

is equal to `0`, while the similar

```
"" + {}
```

is equal to an empty `[object Object]`.

Normal math rules tell me this is odd, but why is it this way?

Comment: Because that's how the language is specified.

Comment: Also, relevant video you should watch: [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: I wish it were easier to search for duplicates of this.

Comment: @Pointy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418721/1-1-and-1-object-object1-whats-going-on-there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token `{` at the beginning of a statement might mean the start of an object literal, or it might mean the start of a statement block. JavaScript assumes it's the latter, a statement block.

Thus

```
{} + ""
```

is just an empty statement block followed by the expression `+ ""`, which will be interpreted as `0` due to the semantics of the unary `+` operator.

In the other one, `{}` is **not** at the beginning of a statement, so it's unambiguously an (empty) object literal.

Comment: Elect me president and I'll make it a law that anybody who talks about JavaScript "wat" stuff has to offer a complete explanation of every single thing.

Comment: I'll elect you president if you immediately ban anybody who posts "wat" questions.